# Equivalence of differentials of equal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, exterior-derivative

I've stumbled upon an ostensible inconsistency which probably has a simple resolution I'm overlooking.

Consider for the time being a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ giving rise to a manifold $M = \mathrm{graph}(f)\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Introducing the two (global) orthonormal unit vectors $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, a chart $(U, \varphi)$ of $M$ is given with $$\varphi(u^{1}) = x^{1}(u^{1})e_{1} + x^{2}(u^{1})e_{2} = u^{1}e_{1} +  f(u^{1})e_{2},$$
where it's fair to say that $x^{1} = u^{1}$ holds.
Let the local tangent vector at point $p = (p_{1}, p_{2})\in M$ now be given by
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u^{1}}\bigg \vert_{p} = e_{1} + f'(p_{1})e_{2}.$$

My question is with respect to the corresponding differentials of the coordinates, $\mathrm{d}x^{1}$ and $\mathrm{d}u^{1}$, the former of which, for a given point $p\in M$, acts on the tangent space $T_{p}\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which happens to be $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. By contrast, the latter acts on the tangent space $T_{p}M$, which only consists of the linear span of $e_{1} + f'(p_{1})e_{2}$. Thus, their domains do not coincide. In addition, both quantities differ with respect to which tangent vectors ($e_{1} \mathrm{vs.} \frac{\partial}{\partial u^{1}}$) they map to 1.  However, by means of $x^{1} = u^{1}$, I would expect their differentials or exterior derivatives, respectively, to be equal as well, i.e., $\mathrm{d}x^{1} = \mathrm{d}u^{1}$.
Does anyone know where there is the obvious fallacy here?

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you used $x^1$ originally is as a function on $M,$ i.e. $x^1: M \to\mathbb{R}.$ This can be seen in the definition,

$$\varphi(u^{1}) = x^{1}(u^{1})\,e_{1} + x^{2}(u^{1})\,e_{2}.$$

The sense that $x^1 = u^1$ is in the sense that they agree as functions on $M.$ Specifically let $u^1: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be the coordinate function and observe that for all $p \in M,$

$$x^1(p) = u^1(p).$$

In this strict sense,

$$d x^1 = d u^1,$$

where $d u^1$ is the smooth coordinate one-form. Recognize that $x^1$ is strictly viewed as a function on $M$ and not on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so there is no contradiction here in terms of the  vectors they take: both $dx^1$ and $du^1$ operate on vectors in $TM.$ The confusion may be arising from the fact that we have another coordinate function $\bar x^1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ on the ambient manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ which agrees with the preceding $x^1$ on the manifold $M$. That is given the insertion map $\iota: M \to \mathbb{R}^2$,

$$\iota^* \bar x^1 = x^1.$$

The only correspondence they have is on the manifold $M$ where we of course have,

$$d( \iota^* \bar x^1 ) = \iota^* d \bar x^1 = d x^1.$$

It is $d\bar x^1$ that takes in vectors in $T\mathbb{R}^2$, while the pullback $\iota^* d\bar x^1 = dx^1$ that takes in vectors of $T M$. Of course, you could just as easily abuse notation and let $d\bar x^1 = d x^1$ but then you have to worry about these issues when they arise.

Comment: It’s not so much the restriction, rather the pullback via the inclusion map (I would interpret the restriction $d\tilde{x}^1|_M$ to mean you restrict to points of $M$, but still consider the vectors tangent to the entire ambient manifold, $\Bbb{R}^2$, in this case. Or said another way, restricting $T\Bbb{R}^2$ to the base $M$)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Agreed with that. I was a bit hesitant to say that: I personally did think that it is the pullback of the insertion map, but I think in work with my supervisor we would often take the restriction in the base points and the inputs. Looking at Lee, i suppose i should say "restriction of $d \bar x^1$ to the tangent space of $M$ but yeah..ill just update my answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo to that end, is there an application to restricting the form to just the manifold but allow it take it vectors in the entirety of the manifold? I think i've seen a similar comment somewhere else and I wondered when I would want that restriction.

Comment: Sure, it’s pretty common, consider normal derivatives. You start with a function $f$ defined on say $\Bbb{R}^n$, and consider a hypersurface $S$, which has a smooth unit normal $\nu$. This $\nu$ is defined only for points $p\in S$, and is of course not tangent to it; it is normal to it. The normal derivative “$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}$”, is defined to be $df(\nu)$, or more explicitly, it is the mapping $S\to\Bbb{R}$ given by $p\mapsto df_p(\nu(p))$. So, the points are restricted to the submanifold, but the tangent vector being fed is not tangent to the submanifold.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ahh, Okay I can see it. Thank you for the improvements to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answers, they helped clarify my confusion